# Inverse Laplace Transform of a function

Tags: laplace-transform, transformation

I am not unable to find the Inverse Laplace transform of the function

$F_n(s) = 1 - e^{-7.97029702970297*10^{-9}*s^{1.01}}$

Then once $F_n(t)$ is found, I need to found $f_n(t)$. I tried using Inverse Laplace Transformations available online but all of them gave me some error.

Comment: Is there a reason you have $s^{1.01}$ because I've never seen a Laplace transform give that result. The answer would be in the form $\delta(t)-L^{-1}\left\{\exp\left(-7.9793*10^{-9}s^{1.01}\right)\right\}$

Comment: Actually, I have been trying to evaluate what the final equation of $f_n(\tau)$ would be, mentioned in a [research paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0093430#pone-0093430-g001). I have gone through different methods but unsuccessfully with all of them. If you could somehow figure the value of $f_n(\tau)$, please let me know.

Comment: Whatever $A$, it is very unlikely that $\exp(As^{1.01})$ has a closed form expression...

Comment: Can the transformation's solution be computed into some form of an integral (like $F_n(\tau) = \int equation$, if not can you somehow compute $f_n(\tau)$?